# trouble receiving the current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an input field, where I would like to display to the user the current date:

```
<input id="uploadformData" ng-model="upload.date" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
```

problem is that it doesn't display the current date but the value conflicts with the ng-model. Without the ng-model being mentioned it works fine.

Below is where the ng-model is reference

```
var module = angular.module("AuthApp", [])
module.controller("MyCntrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();

//To send uploaded documents to a user    
      $scope.userUpload = function(form) {

   var Message = Parse.Object.extend("Upload"); 
var upload = new Message(); 

upload.set("Subject", form.subject); 
upload.set("user", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "_User",
        objectId: document.getElementById("userObjectId").value
    });

upload.set("documentURL", document.getElementById('result').innerHTML);
upload.set("Message", form.message); 
upload.set("Sender", form.sender); 
upload.set("Type", form.type); 
upload.set("Date", form.date); 
upload.save(null, { 
success: function(upload) { 
//success 
        var div = document.getElementById("messageSent");
    div.textContent = "Upload successfully delivered to " + document.getElementById("fullNameId").value;
    scroll(0,0);
      location.reload();

}, 
error: function(upload, error) { 
//failure 
} 
});
```

Comment: You cant use ng-model and value on the element. Set the date in controller and let that show the date in the input.

Comment: thanks for your clarification. How would i be able to set the date in the controller?

Comment: Create a $scope variable for it and set it there. `$scope.date = new Date();` You can then use a date filter to specify the format - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: or maybe since the date is set to current i can just record directly the current date without displaying it to the user for them to confirm

Comment: You can do that. That's a UI design decision you will have to make though. If its not designed to be changed by the user anyway, just do away with it and set the date directly.

Comment: ok thanks. I tried upload.set("Date", document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)); 
but that seems to only display the date on screen and not actually set. I know if i just type date.now() that wont be sufficient

Comment: Use the date filter in the link i posted in the comment above.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i changed it to upload.set("Date",date:'yyyy-MM-dd');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@haxtbh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3535297/haxtbh) has some very good suggestions in the comments.
In your example your are using `ng-model` and `value` on the same input, which is redundant because `ng-model` will overwrite the value.

Take a look at [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/u45440QV7V2iVk1HOS9I?p=info), maybe it will make it clearer for you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.I remove value and did the following how you suggested: <input id="uploadformData" ng-model="upload.date"  ng-model="::currentDate" type="date" />
 but it does not seem to be working. I need to somehow maintain upload.date because it will grab its value and store it in the databse

Comment: First of all, you have 2 ng-models now. Secondly, I would recommend not using `type="date"`, because it requires a very specific format and is not supported in Firefox & IE. If you want to use `upload.date`, just update the line where you set the date to: `upload.set("Date", $filter('date')(localCurrentDate, 'shortDate');`. Don't forget to inject `$filter`

Comment: thank you for your clarification. Just one quite note, can you elaborate on what you mean by inject $filter

Comment: in the sense. what would i define filter as

Comment: One of the core Angular design patterns is [Dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), you really need to read about it. In this example, it means changing: `module.controller("MyCntrl", function($scope) { ... }` to `module.controller("MyCntrl", function($scope, $filter) { ... }`. Perhaps you should go through some tutorials to understand it better, the documentation is pretty 'dry'.

Comment: thank you i will follow your advice and read through the documentation. but i am assuming other things need to be define as well such ReferenceError: localCurrentDate is not defined

Comment: It was defined in the plunker example: `var localCurrentDate = new Date();`